# How to integrate Azure + O365 subscription

Tags: azure, office365

We have a O365 subscription. We have a Azure subscription.
However, the Azure subscription is originally set up with a personal(!) account with was identical to that persons O365 account.
(personal account somebody@company.nl was created and used to setup Azure while that person also had a O365 account with the name somebody@company.nl)

When I log on to Azure using henrov@company.nl I have to choose '**personal**' account to log on to Azure. I do see our subscription. I understand that our Azure subscription has in fact nothing to do with our O365 subscription.

However, if I go to PowerBI in O365 and install a datagateway I need to login with my **O365 account** henrov@company.nl. When I the choose to install a gateway on Azure I get logged in as henrov@company.nl **(School/Work account)**. To be followed by the message: "you have no subscriptions".

I understand what is happening. Somebody@company.nl messed up while setting up Azure. But what can I do to correct this? Would it be better to setup a complete new Azure subscription using a different adress? Or can I somehow merge the existing Azure subscription with our O365 subscription?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you can actually have a Microsoft account created using your corporate e-mail, but it doesn't mean it is an organisational account like the one you have when you create an Office 365 tenant or any other service which relies on Azure AD platform.

Login to your Azure subscription using the service administrator of that subscription (the personal Microsoft account) and follow this guide to transfer the subscription to another tenant owner, that is, the global administrator of your corporate tenant.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-subscription-transfer

Finally, change the directory associated with that subscription.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-add-office-365-tenant-to-azure-subscription

You can do the latter only if you want.